# How to update listbox with progress bar GUI during execution

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, progress-bar

I have a listbox in a wpf window thats bound to a list in a viewmodel object. When I run a method in the viewmodel object it processes members of the list and each member has a progress. I would like to have the gui update continuously during execution. As it is now, it only updates gui when the processing is finished.

Here I have tried to create a small example of what I have right now:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_MVVM_Thread_Progressbar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_MVVM_Thread_Progressbar"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:TestViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TestWorker.TestList}">
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Bisque">
              <ProgressBar.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Progress}" Value="0">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
              </ProgressBar.Style>
            </ProgressBar>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Background="Transparent"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>



    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="TestRun" Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}"></Button>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedIdx}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowl.xaml.cs:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_MVVM_Thread_Progressbar
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }

  public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private WorkingClass _testWorker;

    private DelegateCommand _testRunCommand;

    public DelegateCommand TestRunCommand
    {
      get { return _testRunCommand; }
      set { _testRunCommand = value; }
    }

    public WorkingClass TestWorker
    {
      get { return _testWorker; }
      set { _testWorker = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TestWork"); }
    }

    private int _selectedIdx;

    public int SelectedIdx
    {
      get { return _selectedIdx; }
      set { _selectedIdx = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIdx"); }
    }


    public TestViewModel()
    {
      _testWorker = new WorkingClass();
      _testRunCommand = new DelegateCommand(TestRun, canRun);
    }

    public async void TestRun()
    {
      //await Task.Run(() => _testWorker.Work());
      _testWorker.Work();
    }

    private bool canRun()
    {
      return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }

  }

  public class WorkingClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private ObservableCollection<TestObject> _testList;

    public ObservableCollection<TestObject> TestList
    {
      get { return _testList; }
      set { _testList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TestList"); }
    }

    public WorkingClass()
    {
      _testList = new ObservableCollection<TestObject>();
      _testList.Add(new TestObject("Object A"));
      _testList.Add(new TestObject("Object B"));
      _testList.Add(new TestObject("Object C"));
      RaisePropertyChanged("TestList");

    }

    public void Work()
    {
      foreach (var obj in TestList)
      {
        obj.TestWork();
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }

  }

  public class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
      get { return _name; }
      set { _name = value; }
    }

    private int _progress;

    public int Progress
    {
      get { return _progress; }
      set { _progress = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Progress"); }
    }

    public TestObject(string name)
    {
      this._name = name;
      _progress = 0;
    }

    public void TestWork()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        Progress++;
      }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to use ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged but this it seems not to be enough.

Eventually I would like to be able to have the same effect using async/await call from the TestViewModel.TestRun().

Could someone perhaps offer some insights on this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the UI to update while work is happening, you're going to need to do the work in a thread/task. You can bind a progress bar to a progress property and safely update the progress property from the worker thread without invoking into the UI thread. However, if you want to mess with an ObservableCollection in the worker thread/task, you'll have to create the collection in the UI thread and invoke into the UI thread to interact with the collection.

Comment: Thanks.. but I want a separate progress bar for/in each listbox item, so then I would need a list of progresses in the viewmodel and bind theese to the listbox?? I would like it if there was little bit more beautiful way.

Comment: That sounds like a collection of "progress items" bound to an ItemsControl that has an ItemTemplate to display a progress bar for each one. Give the ProgressItem class a scalar Progress property, and you're golden. Just make sure you create *and populate* the ObservableCollection in the UI thread. I *think* you should be able to safely index it from another thread. If not, your task startup code could create a thread-safe copy of the collection with references to the same ProgressItems

Comment: @ErikThysell, I literally copy and pasted your code, commented out _testWorker.Work(), uncommented await Task.Run(() => _testWorker.Work()); and it worked exactly as you want.

Comment: @cjmurph yes.. fantastic, don't know why I didn't get that at first... :) Thank a lot for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

I think the current reason that you have the UI only updating once completed, is that you are running all of this on the UI thread. I would instead try this:

```
Task.Run(async delegate
{ 
   await _testWorker.Work();
});
```

Or

```
Task.Run(() =>
{ 
    _testWorker.Work();
});
```

Or

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{ 
    _testWorker.Work();
});
```

Or

```
var newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_testWorker.Work());
newThread.Start();
```

This will return back to the UI instantly but allow your code to continue.

**Note:** You will have to be careful about the use of objects off the UI thread. ObservableCollections can only be created on the same thread as the dispatcher that handles the UI work.  If you are using two-way binding, again you have to be careful about thread safety.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to make it work... I get the same result using this / running it in a thread..

Comment: Hmm, then Task.Run may be running it on the current thread anyway. Try using Task.Factory.StartNew() instead of Task.Run(). Failing that I have updated the answer with a Thread version.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully done this in the past using a `BackgroundWorker`.

```
public class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public TestObject() {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker() {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true
        };
        worker.DoWork += DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += WorkProgress;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkFinished;
    }

    public int Progress
    {
      get { return _progress; }
      set { _progress = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Progress"); }
    }

    // Begin doing work
    public void TestWork() {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs eventArgs) {
        worker.ReportProgress(0, "Work started");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            worker.ReportProgress(i, "Message");
        }
    }

    // Fires when the progress of a job changes.
    private void WorkProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        // Do something with the progress here
        Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    // Fires when a job finishes.
    private void WorkFinished(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        // The work finished. Do something?
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      // NOTE: If you're running C#6 use the null conditional operator for this check.
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
    }
}
```

A `BackgroundWorker` basically runs everything on a separate thread and reports back when its progress changes or it finishes working. You can pull out the ProgressPercentage from its progress report and use that in the UI. Hope that helps. To keep the example simple I didn't include some of your code but that should given you an idea of how it can be done.